# Get deployment age or last restart time for a pod using Prometheus on Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, label, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to develop dashboards on Grafana that tells the status of different pods with the help of kube labels. Eg: I am able to get the restarts using this label: kube_deployment_status_observed_generation

What i want is the age, For a deployment we can get the age on kuberenetes cluster using,
kubectl get deployments
NAME READY UP-TO-DATE AVAILABLE AGE
deployemnt-test-state 1/1 1 1 6d2h

I want this same age to be shown in Grafana but I am not able to find this “age” anywhere in any label.

Can anyone help me where and how i can get these variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about object creation time metrics [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) exposes a creation time for almost all the objects it tracks. The metric name follows the pattern  `kube_<OBJECT>_created`  and will include values for the name of the object and the namespace where it lives. The value is an epoch timestamp to the millisecond.

For example, the [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) creation series is called  `kube_cronjob_created`.

To calculate the average age of all CronJobs running use this query:

```
avg(time() - kube_cronjob_created ).
```

In your case you can use metrics `kube_deployment_created` to check the age of deployment.

More information you can find here: [kube-state-metrics](https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-6-kube-state-metrics-14f4e7c8710b).